# Why isn't tailwindCSS styling showing in Next.js pre-rendered HTML?

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I'm using next.js 13+ and App router with tailwindCSS. I found out that Next's pre-rendered HTML does not contain tailwindCSS styling.
I want to know the reason why it's happened and how to fix it. or is it intentional?

tried `optimizeCss: true` in `next.config.js` but didn't work.